# Is it possible to make the following combined table?

Tags: tables

[image]

Is it possible to make this combined table?

Edit - I have done this so far:

---

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
%opening
\title{Tabla combinada}
\author{JMDA}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}
    
\begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Características de la Zeolita LZY-52 en forma sódica y forma protónica}
        \begin{tabular}{p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}}
            \toprule
            Zeolita & FRX \%p & & $(Si/Al)_{FRX}$ Molar & \% Crist. & $a_0(A^0)$ & (Si/Al) DRX & Área Específica ($m^2/g$) & Acidez total (mmol $NH_3/g$) & Máximo de desorción (°C) \\
             & $SiO_2$ & $Al_2O_3$ & & & & & & & \\
             \midrule   
            NaY & 52.5 & 15.9 & 2.8 & 100 & 24.6 & 12.9 & 510 & 1.77 & 180 \\
            HY5 & 7.5 & 19.8 & 2.5 & 73 & 24.58 & 3.4 & 716 & 2.97 & 270 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table*}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

I don't know how to merge the cells I'm interested in.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community! Of course it is possible. What you try so far, where you stuck in your effort?

Comment: Keywords to search for: `tabular`, `multirow` and maybe `booktabs`.

Comment: Some basic about how to write tables you can find in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Answer (score 1):

- instead of use the `multicolumn` package I would rather use `twocolumn` option for `article` document class
- for table code I would use `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (later is for consistent writing of units and for `S` columns)
- for chemistry symbols I would use the `mhchem` package (up to date version, i.e. `version=4`)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,       % <---
               twoside]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{tabularray}         % <--- new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}        % <--- new
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}  % <--- new


\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]  % <--- changed
    \centering
    \caption{Características de la Zeolita LZY-52 en forma sódica y forma protónica}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=5pt,
             colspec = {@{} l *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=2.2}]}
                                   X[0.9, c, si={table-format=1.1}]
                                   X[0.9, c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                              *{3}{X[0.9, c, si={table-format=2.2}]} 
                                   X[1.5, c, si={table-format=1.2}]
                                   X[1.2, c, si={table-format=3.0}] 
                        @{}},
             cell{1}{1,4-Z} = {r=2}{}, % <--- set multirow cell where needed
             row{1,2} = {guard, font=\small},
             }
    \toprule
Zeolita
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  FRX \%p  % <--- set multicolumn cell
            &       & \ce{(Si/Al)_{FRX}} Molar
                            & \% Crist.
                                    & $a_0(A^0)$
                                            & (Si/Al) DRX
                                                    & Área Específica (\unit{\square\metre\per\gram})
                                                            & Acidez total (\ce{NH3} \unit{\mmol\per\gram})
                                                                    & Máximo de desorción (\unit{\degreeCelsius}) \\
    \midrule
    & \ce{SiO2}
            & \ce{Al2O3}
                    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
             \midrule
NaY & 52.5 & 15.9   & 2.8   & 100   & 24.6  & 12.9  & 510   & 1.77  & 180   \\
HY5 & 7.5  & 19.8   & 2.5   &  73   & 24.58 &  3.4  & 716   & 2.97  & 270   \\
            \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Marcos Delgado, any news?